# "This one is a question, too" vs "This one is a question. Too"

Tags: pronunciation, punctuation, spoken-english, commas

Is "This one is a question, too" the same as "This one is a question. Too"?

Is the "Too" understood in the second case? Are the two spoken differently?

Comment: If we split up a sentence using periods. Like. This. We are deviating from standard English. You normally see it for emphasis e.g. This. Stops. Now. So your second example has more emphasis, and would be spoken with a longer pause after 'question' than if a comma had been used.

Comment: By "the same", do you mean with the same meaning or grammatically? And why would the "too" be understood in the second case? After all, it is included there explicitly.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, both, and the tone/elocution. So, do you mean it (I meant the meaning that it too is a question) doesn't need to be understood as it's already mentioned with it? Yes, apart from it not being standard English, it sounds a bit wrong generally, *too*.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder Oh, I see. When we say "understood", we sometimes mean that a missing element is inferred, so that was what I was thinking of. Now I "understand"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both have the same meaning, but the second sentence places more emphasis on the "too" by using a full stop to separate the sentence. This emphasis is also supported by a longer *pause* after saying the first part of the sentence. So this makes the "too" stand out a bit more, so yes they are said a bit differently.